# Why the output textbox doesn't show the return value my function gives?

Tags: c#

I intend to show the results in the textbox. My code is like this:

```
private void run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GeneticAlgorithm MyGeneticAlgorithm = new GeneticAlgorithm();
    GeneticAlgorithm.GAoutput ShowResult = MyGeneticAlgorithm.GA();

    string output;

    output = ShowResult;

    this.Output.Text = output;
}

class GeneticAlgorithm
{
    public void reset()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("fine");
    }
    public void Initial()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Good");
    }
    public class GAoutput
    {
        public string Generation;
    }
    public GAoutput GA()
    {
        GAoutput OneGeneration = new GAoutput();
        OneGeneration.Generation = "bad";
        return OneGeneration;
    }
}
```

after running, it gives me results as:
WindowsFormsApplication1.GeneticAlgorithm+GAoutput

Anyone can help me? thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your `ShowResult` variable is not a string, so when you assigned it to one, .NET implicitly converted it into a string. Since there was no `ToString()` method, it gave you the generic type definition string instead ("WindowsFormsApplication1.GeneticAlgorithm+GAoutput").

It looks like you want to output the `Generation` field, which *is* a string, so just change:

```
output = ShowResult;
```

to

```
output = ShowResult.Generation;
```

and it should start working.

Also, if you aren't planning on doing much else to get a new `Generation`, you could really shorten up that code, all the way down to:

```
this.Output.Text = (new GeneticAlgorithm()).GA().Generation;
```

You might also want to think about keeping a local instance of `GeneticAlgorithm` so you don't have to keep creating new instances.

Answer (score 0):

You must decide what string to return for instances of those classes.

Then override the [ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method for each of those classes to return the appropriate string.